# bluehost error : domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel, cpanel, bluehost

I have uploaded my laravel project successfully in my Namecheap cPanel and the website is showing without any error but while uploading in bluehost cPanel and run that website into browser it shows error

```
domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

though I have followed same steps for uplaod my project in `bluehost cPanel` as I upload in `Namecheap cPanel`.

I have check the folder permission also. It is `755`

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for errors, if any is logged

Answer (score 0):

Do the basic:

- check if you included `.env` file in your app
- clear chache: `php artisan config:cache`
- clear routes: `php artisan route:cache`
- generate app key: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: `.env` file is included. But dot file is hidden there. I used `&showhidden=1&saveoption=1` after the url and then got the `.env` file. Normally it is not shown there.

Comment: on linux to see hidden files use control + H

Comment: I got that hidden file and change as my need. But still got the error